# Reading 2 huge numbers from a file in different strings inversed

Tags: c, string, file, io, strtok

I have an input file where I have 2 very long numbers (somewhere at 10^8 digits) separated by a space. What I have to do is to read them , both of them from the last digit to first and put them in separate strings. Here is an example for 2 short numbers:

```
1234 5678
```

My program needs the numbers like a[ ]={4,3,2,1} and n[ ]={8,7,6,5} to work.

```
FILE *f;
char str[100000000],*ptr,avect[100000000],nvect[100000000];
f = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
    fgets(str, MAX_NR_DIGITS, f); //read the whole line into a string
    strrev (str); //inverse the string and I am gonna read n firstly and a secondly
    nvect=strtok(str," ");
```

Here I stopped, because I don't know how strtok works. After mirroring, I have to give nvect number n in a string and give avect number a in a string. I think is a good solving method, BUT if you know a better one by elapsed time point of view, I am open. Thank you for help!

Comment: `nvect=strtok(str," ");` --> `strcpy(nvect, strtok(str," \n"));` then `strcpy(avect, strtok(NULL," \n"));`

Comment: It could be worth allocating such memory instead of using local storage. It is too much for MSVC stack anyway.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, are you sure there is not strtok(str, " ") at nvect?

Comment: @EmmanuelBan Since `str` contains newline, So `\n` must be included to delimiter. E.g  `fgets` ==> `1234 5678\n` ==> `strrev` ==> `\n8756 4321`

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why I get error, it stops working in CodeBlocks.

Comment: `char str[100000000],avect[100000000],nvect[100000000];` These are too big for the stack. Use static (E.g `static char str[100000000],...`) or allocate by `malloc`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I checked where the error can be and is right at the 2 strcopy you wrote. Can you check again if there isn't any error?

Comment: If there are two numbers in the file and it can be read, I think that there is no problem.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY The file has "m" lines, but I wrote `for(I=0;i<m;i++)` before reading a line.

Comment: I think that there is no problem. What I'd like to say is that `str` needs a combined length of two(+2). E.g str need length(avect)+space(1)+length(nvect)+newline(1)+NUL(1). And if there is only one number per line, `strtok` will return `NULL` so it will not work properly.

Comment: As you said, at strrev it becomes `\n8765 4321`. I have to give nvect only `8765`. For that I have to make a strtok from begin to " " between n and a. What about that \n from str[0]?

Comment: I said again, Use `" \n"` as delimiter.

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/sGuVZM) , Read [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) _The function searches for the first character which is not contained in delim._

Comment: Thank you so much for help, @BLUEPIXY! Tell me how can I give you a vote or something, if is possible.

Comment: You are welcome. 
It is not necessary in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Basically how Strtok works is in the string provided it reads until it reaches a certain character or "delimiter" , in your case space, or " " is what you're using since the numbers are separated by a space, and  then returns the string up until it the delimiter, here's a helpful link that might help
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Comment: Thank you, but I already did it. I just need a clear explanation, or example.

Comment: say your have a string | char* test =  "Hello World" |, if you do              strtok(test, " "), it will return "Hello" because it read each character, reached the space, and then it stops and returns what's before the space, does that help?

Comment: in that since the space is the delimiter like I said before

Comment: and how can I get what is after space?

Comment: use this:  strtok(NULL, "\n") I believe

Comment: Thank you so much for explanation!